# How to get an icon from the current theme by name?

Tags: bash, icons, themes

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787249/how-to-get-icon-from-current-system-theme-in-bash-script-ubuntu) on Stack Overflow, the reason my question is different is that I can't be certain that the path to an icon will always be the same (for example, some themes use SVG, some use PNG).

I would like to get a full path to an icon from a bash script knowing only its name.

What I mean by *name* is the one that's used in desktop entries.

For example, here's a line from a `firefox.desktop` file on my Ubuntu:

```
Icon=firefox
```

Somehow that's enough for my system to figure out exactly what the path to an icon is. How can I leverage this functionality in my scripts?

Just in case, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

A search for "gnome desktop file format":

- brought me here: [Desktop files: putting your application in the desktop menus - GNOME](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)
- which links to here: [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)
- which, in the "Recognized desktop entry keys" chapter, links to here: [Icon Theme Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec)
- which is where I gave up.